# Ubuntu 22.04, After Update, Audio and Video Devices Don't Work

Tags: sound, 22.04, video

After a recent update, Ubuntu gives me USB errors on startup and won't recognize my Logitech C270 USB webcam, Logitech H570e USB headset, or AMD Family 17h stereo speakers connected to the audio line out port. My user account has been added to the audio and video groups and all of the devices work on my other computer.

dmesg errors:

```
[    1.758723] hub 1-6:1.0: hub_ext_port_status failed (err = -71)

[    2.292046] usb 1-6: clear tt 1 (8040) error -71
[    2.414327] usb 1-6.1: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/all
[    2.414364] usb 1-6.1: can't read configurations, error -71
[    2.417067] usb 1-6: clear tt 1 (8040) error -71

[    3.201320] usb 1-6.1: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/all
[    3.201362] usb 1-6.1: can't read configurations, error -71

[    3.582786] usb 1-6-port1: cannot reset (err = -71)

[    4.005270] hub 1-6:1.0: hub_ext_port_status failed (err = -71)
[    4.284026] usb 1-6.1: new low-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[    4.441487] usb 1-6.1: device descriptor read/all, error -71
[    4.540026] usb 1-6.1: new low-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[    4.704691] usb 1-6.1: device descriptor read/all, error -71
[    4.719258] usb 1-6-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

The hardware is present, with some devices unclaimed by the kernel.

```
$ sudo lshw -C sound
  *-usb:2                   
       description: Audio device
       product: Logitech H570e Stereo
       vendor: Logitech Inc
       physical id: c
       bus info: usb@1:c
       version: 1.03
       serial: 00000000
       capabilities: usb-2.00 audio-control
       configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
  *-multimedia UNCLAIMED
       description: Audio device
       product: TU104 HD Audio Controller
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.1
       version: a1
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7080000-f7083fff
  *-usb:0 UNCLAIMED
       description: Video
       product: Webcam C270
       vendor: Logitech, Inc.
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@5:3.1.1
       version: 0.12
       serial: 39A6CCD0
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia UNCLAIMED
       description: Audio device
       product: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
       physical id: 0.3
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.3
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7800000-f7807fff
```

All other USB devices work and the webcam + headset are recognized by the USB controller.

```
$ lsusb | grep Logitech
Bus 005 Device 005: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:0a56 Logitech, Inc. Logitech H570e Stereo
```

I'm not sure how to begin fixing this problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rolling back the kernel](https://www.howtogeek.com/740797/how-to-roll-back-the-kernel-in-linux/) from `5.15.0-1027-oracle` to `5.15.0-58-generic` allowed the OS to recognize my audio devices. I don't have any USB errors when booting the older kernel either.

Reverting the gpu driver from `nvidia-driver-515` to `nvidia-driver-470` allowed the OS to recognize my webcam.